# Populating and passing complex object from MVC2 view to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have following code in my MVC2 view:

```
<tr class="edit" style="display:none">
    <td>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpFields", new SelectList(Model.Fields, "FieldID", "NiceName", whiteout.FieldID)) %>      
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpStartTimeh", new SelectList(Model.Hours, whiteout.StartHour.Hour.ToString("0,0")))%>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpStartTimem", new SelectList(Model.Minutes, whiteout.StartHour.Minute.ToString("0,0")))%>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpStartTimet", new SelectList(Model.AMPM, whiteout.StartHour.Hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"))%>
        -
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpEndTime", new SelectList(Model.Hours, whiteout.EndHour.Hour > 12 ? (whiteout.EndHour.Hour - 12).ToString("0,0") : whiteout.EndHour.Hour.ToString("0,0")))%>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpEndTimem", new SelectList(Model.Minutes, whiteout.EndHour.Minute.ToString("0,0")))%>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("drpEndTimet", new SelectList(Model.AMPM, whiteout.EndHour.Hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"))%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= Html.DropDownList("drprepeat", new SelectList(Model.RepeatList,whiteout.Repeats))%>
    </td>
    <td>
     Active
    </td>
    <td>            
             <a class="icon-button-cancel" href='<%: Url.Action("EditWhiteOut", "Settings", new {Id = whiteout.WhiteoutID}) %>'>
    <img src='<%: Url.Content("~/static/Images/expanded.png") %>' alt="Delete this device" />
</a>
            <a class="icon-button-success" href="#">
            <img src="/static/images/gear.png" alt="Edit this device" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to create an object of type Whiteout class and populate it with values selected by user from dropdowns and send to settingcontroller's EditWhiteout action method instead of passing only new {Id = whiteout.WhiteoutID}. How can I do this ?

Please suggest solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC provides some automatic mapping on form values from the view back into the controller action.  Usually you would use a strongly type view i.e. at the top of the page you will have something 
like 
`Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<namespace.Whiteout>`

The names of the dropdown lists need to match those of the properties in the Whiteout class and the controller action will expect a return value of the model type i.e.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EditWhiteout(WhiteOut tseItem)
 { //method body here
```

The rest should just happen as if by magic.  If you are getting confused by the dropdowns it is sometimes easier to replace them with simple inputs until you get the send/receive part working - then change to dropdown.

Comment: I have this at the top: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EnviroTracker.ViewModels.WhiteoutViewModel>" %> and I dont have strongly typed dropdownlists because I have collection typed strongly view. Do I need to use Html.beginform and wrap above html in it ?

Comment: The dropdown lists are not strongly typed as they are only used to populate an input element.  But you do need to use a form element as this is how the the page knows how to pass the data back to the server (There is no difference between this and basic html pages).  I tend to use the Html.beginform but this is mainly because that's how I started learning MVC.  The form will need a submit mechanism which can be a simple submit button. As mentioned I would get a simplified page working using basic textboxes until you get the post mechanism working - then you can re-add the dropdown boxes